# How to break down a list by one of its items?

Tags: python

How can I break down this list into two smaller lists by the `"."` character?

Example:

```
word_list = ["I", "love", "icecream", ".", "I", "want", "to", "eat", "chip", "."]

smaller_list_1 = ["I", "love", "icecream", "."]

smaller_list_2 = ["I", "want", "to", "eat", "chip", "."]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do this with a string.
Instead of a list, make a string like this:

```
foo = "I love icecream. I want to eat chip."
```

Then use the split() function:

```
list = foo.split(".")
```

And you will get this:

```
["I love icecream", "I want to eat chip"]
```

Then, you split the 2 list items by a space:

```
list1 = list[0].split(" ")
list2 = list[1].split(" ")
```

And you will get this:

```
["I", "love", "iceceam"]
["I", "want", "to", "eat", "chip"]
```

Comment: you’re missing “.” in each of your output lists

Comment: Yes, the only problem with this method is that is gets rid of the periods.